# Openlayers ol.geom.Circle

Tags: openlayers-3

In ol.geom.Polygon I can send an array of arrays that represent different map coordinates. This lets me create a polygon with a "hole" in it by sending the first array of coordinates in clockwise order, and the subsequent coordinates smaller, in counter-clockwise order, like so:

```
var vertices = [
    ol.proj.transform([-63.63, 49.45], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-129.02, 49.45], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-129.02, 23.80], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-63.63, 23.80], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-63.63, 49.45], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
];
var inner = [
    ol.proj.transform([-106.56, 41.16], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-97.73, 41.16], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-97.73, 37.66], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-106.56, 37.66], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-106.56, 41.16], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
];
var poly = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([vertices, inner])
});
```

However, ol.geom.Circle doesn't work that way. Canvas, however, allows the use of an optional flag in their spec for the arc() method for drawing a circle counter-clockwise. I would like to have the ability to send the reverse flag to the ol.geom.Circle method. I also need to send and array of arrays of geometry data to the Circle method, just like you can with ol.geom.Polygon.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with ol.geom.Circle class. I think the ol3 api is clear on that.
However there is a workaround:

Instead of working with ol.geom.Circle you can create circular polygon and then append the linear ring of the hole. To do so:

```
var circleCenter = [2633654,4572283];


var circleLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
var circleStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
        width: 5
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4)'
    })
});
var circleLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: circleLayerSource,
  style: circleStyle
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    circleLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: circleCenter,
    zoom: 10
  })
});


function drawCircleWithHole(){
var circleGeom = new ol.geom.Polygon([
     createCirclePointCoords(circleCenter[0],circleCenter[1],30000,60)
]); 
var inCircleCoords = createCirclePointCoords(circleCenter[0],circleCenter[1],10000,60);
circleGeom.appendLinearRing(new ol.geom.LinearRing(inCircleCoords));
circleLayer.getSource().addFeature(new ol.Feature(circleGeom));
}




/**
* pass the x, y center of the circle
* the radius of circle
* and the number of points to form the circle
* 60 points seems to be fine in terms of visual impact
*/
function createCirclePointCoords(circleCenterX,circleCenterY,circleRadius,pointsToFind) {
    var angleToAdd = 360/pointsToFind;
    var coords = [];  
    var angle = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<pointsToFind;i++){
        angle = angle+angleToAdd;
        var coordX = circleCenterX + circleRadius * Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180);
        var coordY = circleCenterY + circleRadius * Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180);
        coords.push([coordX,coordY]);
    }
    return coords;
}


drawCircleWithHole();
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/k5qpwcu5/1/)